# Text doesn't fit in column

Tags: tables

This is my document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[landscape, margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\title{ABC}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{First}
\begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|*{8}{c|}}
            \textbf{A} &  
            \textbf{B} &  
            \textbf{C} &  
            \textbf{D} &
            \textbf{E} &               
            \textbf{F} & 
            \textbf{G} & 
            \textbf{H}\\
        \hline
            It's ok & 
            It's ok &
            It's ok &
            It's ok &
            It's ok &
            It's ok &
            It's ok &
            It' too long, it's too long, it's too looooooooooooooooooooooog\\
        \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Overfull \hbox (2099.37712pt too wide)
It's possibile to have multiple lines in a column box (double slash doens't work)?
Like:

```
it' too long, it's too long,  
it's too looooooooooooooooooooooog
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Unfortunately, your minimal working example does not reproduce the warning you quote. (In fact it only warns about not having defined an author name). An "Overfull \hbox" warning, though with a different value, is issued when removing `\usepackage[landscape, margin=0.5in]{geometry}`. How exactly does your actual documen setup look like? The available textwidth might crucially influence which approach to use in order to avoid a table overflowing into the margin.

Comment: `2099.37712pt too wide` means about 70 cm too wide.  I wonder what's the contents of your real table?

Comment: This is the only file I've created. Last column is a description, so it's much long. I'm trying to report a excel document that I've for reach a elegant look.

Answer (score 2):

For automatic linebreaks in columns, use the fixed width `p` column type with an appropriate width argument instead of `c` which itself it alswys as wide as its widest entry. In the following MWE, I also added `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}`(needs the `array` package)  to make sure, the contents in this specific cell are right aligned instead of justified, which is the default alignment in `p` type columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[landscape, margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\title{ABC}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{First}
\begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|*{7}{c|}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5.5cm}|}
            \textbf{A} &  
            \textbf{B} &  
            \textbf{C} &  
            \textbf{D} &
            \textbf{E} &               
            \textbf{F} & 
            \textbf{G} & 
            \textbf{H}\\
        \hline
            It's ok & 
            It's ok &
            It's ok &
            It's ok &
            It's ok &
            It's ok &
            It's ok &
            It' too long, it's too long, it's too looooooooooooooooooooooog\\
        \end{tabular}
\end{center}


\begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|*{7}{c|}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5.5cm}|}
            \textbf{A} &  
            \textbf{B} &  
            \textbf{C} &  
            \textbf{D} &
            \textbf{E} &               
            \textbf{F} & 
            \textbf{G} & 
            \textbf{H}\\
        \hline
            It's ok & 
            It's ok &
            It's ok &
            It's ok &
            It's ok &
            It's ok &
            It's ok &
            It' too long, it's too long,\newline it's too loooooooooooooooooooog\\
        \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

---

The `makecell` package and its eponymous command could also be a useful tool:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[landscape, margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell}
\title{ABC}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{First}
\begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|*{8}{c|}}
            \textbf{A} &  
            \textbf{B} &  
            \textbf{C} &  
            \textbf{D} &
            \textbf{E} &               
            \textbf{F} & 
            \textbf{G} & 
            \textbf{H}\\
        \hline
            It's ok & 
            It's ok &
            It's ok &
            It's ok &
            It's ok &
            It's ok &
            It's ok &
            \makecell[lt]{It' too long, it's too long,\\ it's too looooooooooooooooooooooog}\\
        \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

---

If you want to get automatic linebreaks inside of a table cell while maing sure, the table is exactly as wide as te textwidth, use the `X` type column from the `tabularx` package inside of a `tabularx` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[landscape, margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\title{ABC}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{First}

        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{7}{c|}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X|}
            \textbf{A} &  
            \textbf{B} &  
            \textbf{C} &  
            \textbf{D} &
            \textbf{E} &               
            \textbf{F} & 
            \textbf{G} & 
            \textbf{H}\\
        \hline
            It's ok & 
            It's ok &
            It's ok &
            It's ok &
            It's ok &
            It's ok &
            It's ok &
            It' too long, it's too long, it's too looooooooooooooooooooooog It' too long, it's too long, it's too looooooooooooooooooooooog It' too long, it's too long, it's too looooooooooooooooooooooog\\
        \end{tabularx}


\end{document}
```